# How do I serve static files only to authorized users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-staticfile

I have a collection of Excel spreadsheets that I'd like to serve in my ASP.NET 5 webapp only to authorized users.

1. Where should I store the files? I assume in wwwroot (e.g., wwwroot/files).
2. If in wwwroot, how do I allow access only to authorized users? (I'd like to serve them up as a [Authorize] FileResult from the controller, but this still leaves the files open to direct access through a URL I believe.)
3. How do I reference a location in wwwroot through my FileResult action in the controller?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, they should go in `wwwroot`.  Currently there is no built-in way to secure `wwwroot` directories.  But creating a middleware module to accomplish it is pretty straightforward.  There is an easy to follow tutorial [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx).

If you're not familiar with developing middleware, I posted a GitHub project that shows how to create middleware in three easy steps.  You can download the project [here](https://github.com/ClintBailiff/MiddlewareDemo).

You don't need a controller to access static files.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Looking into it. (I'm only using an action because I want to send notifications when files are downloaded.)

Comment: Or you could put them *outside* of wwwroot, where the static file middleware doesn't touch. Like a good old App_Data folder (which admittedly you have to create yourself)

Comment: @Gabe - You could add that functionality to your middleware.  And maybe mark my post as the accepted answer. :-)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Only stumble I encountered from the tutorial you linked is to make sure that the reference to the middleware in startup.cs/Configure was after app.UseIdentity(), but still before app.UseStaticFiles().

Comment: Actually let me be clearer, you absolutely should *NOT* put them under wwwroot, as there is a risk that the static file middleware will server them, as it's meant to do for any file under wwwroot it understands. Putting things under wwwroot is a huge possible information disclosure risk if you mess up your middleware order.

Comment: But if you put things *outside* wwwroot, in Core 2.0 at least... they're not Published to production.

Comment: @philw: Not by default, but you just have to include the directory in your project file.

Comment: Just to back up @blowdart: The private spreadsheets should go in `wwwroot` only if _all_ the files in `wwwroot` are private.  Public and private data should not be stored side by side.  (See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585284/9069356).)

Comment: Please modify your answer. There is build-in middleware UseAuthorization + FallbackPolicy, UseStaticFiles. It's explicitly described in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization)

Answer (score 15):

For authentication check while retrieving file:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
            {
                if (!context.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/excelfiles"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Not authenticated");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This will work only if the authentication scheme being used is the default authentication scheme, otherwise `HttpContext.User` will not be updated (see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1318)).

Answer (score 10):

in .net core create a dedicated directory www in same level as wwwroot, and use the following code:

```
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}

[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRole")]
public IActionResult Performance()
{
    return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
                                     "www", "MyStaticFile.pdf"), "application/pdf");
}
```

Based on the following answer (for .netCore): [static file authorization](https://medium.com/@tanaka_733/static-file-authorization-in-asp-net-core-mvc-26c1069073c1)

Comment: Note that the action above can be requested by a view. Say for example that the /Home/Performance returns an image/png. Another Action - kind of a Home/ParentPerformance, could return View() the standard way, and inside the view you could reference the protected static resource. For example: `<img src="~/home/performance"  style="width:100%;background:white;" />`
This has the advantage that you are still serving an HTML envelope with your shared _Layout menu system and look and feel, while still maintaining security on the static file.

Comment: BTW, I was serving PDF till recently, only to discover that **pdf experience on Android is terrible**, forcing download/cancel, and ending up with users not getting a smooth experience, unlike IOS, including some zooming out of screen boundaries. In short, not what you'd expect. Since then I'm exporting the PDF to PNG using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org), and this aligns perfectly with the `<img>` inside an html mentioned above.

Comment: Also described here: [Static files in ASP.NET Core: Static file authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-file-authorization)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a login form (Login.html), a simple solution is to redirect the user to the login page if user is not authenticated and he's requesting a protected resource (file under /protected folder). In Startup.cs, in Configure method insert this code:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/protected"))
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Login.html");
        return;
    }
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Comment: but how you will ensure that files under /wwwroot are protected ?

Comment: If you just remove the control on path, everithing is protected:
     if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated )
         {...

Comment: This will work only if the authentication scheme being used is the default authentication scheme, otherwise `HttpContext.User` will not be updated (see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1318)).

Comment: There is the Authorization/Authentication subsystem in Asp.Net Core that handles the login/logout process as well, and manual redirect to a login page is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simple example, but it can be changed to check for specific roles, and the code can be moved out of the Startup.cs for more flexibility.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
               {
                   if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
                       && context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/excelfiles"))
                   {
                       throw new Exception("Not authenticated");
                   }
                   await next.Invoke();
               });
```

Comment: Might be better to use `context.Response.StatusCode = 403` instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: I think it depends on the situation. In my apps exceptions are caught, logged, and then a generic error page displays. For API's I would return the 403.

Comment: This will work only if the authentication scheme being used is the default authentication scheme, otherwise `HttpContext.User` will not be updated (see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1318)).

Comment: @Dominus.Vobiscum I believe that it is due to a problem of not configuring the middleware (Authentication middleware) correctly. An authentication scheme should always be specified (default or not). Default is just a fallback, but always one scheme should be configured/registered/specified. `HttpContext.User` is a very essential hub to get started authenticating/authorizing.

Answer (score 0):

To secure your files and available them to the authenticated users, easily create a folder named 'staticfiles' outside of the 'wwwroot' folder. then suppose you want to restric user access to some books, so create a 'Books' folder under the 'staticfiles' and then update your "Program.cs" or your middleware pipeline like this:

```
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    
    OnPrepareResponse = (ctx) =>
    {
        var context = ctx.Context;
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/staticfiles/Books"))
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                context.Response.Redirect($"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{context.Request.PathBase}" + "/Identity/Account/Login");

            }
        }
    },
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "staticfiles")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles",

});

app.UseAuthorization();
```