# Blazor WASM: Secure a video stream - controller only accessible for authorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Info: I'm using the default Visual Studio (*16.10.0 Preview 1.0*) ASP.NET hosted Blazor WASM template with IdentityServer4 individual accounts.(*ASP.NET Core 6 Preview 1*)

I'd like the video stream only to be accessible by authorized users but `[Authorize]` attribute doesn't work here on the controller, I'm getting a `Status Code: 401`, while the user has logged in and thus has been authorized by the application. `[Authorize]` works with controllers for database access for example.

I think maybe it doesn't work with the `video` tag because the client accesses the controller directly from the `video` tag option: `<source src="/VideoStream/@videoFileName"` so no authorization headers are being sent. I've seen the same problem when devs want to protect/authorize downloading a file. I've read some blogs on that topic and tried some code snippets, but none of them work in my Blazor WASM app.

Without the `[Authorize]` attribute and if you know the path to the controller and the filename of the video (*e.q. /VideoStream/test.mp4*) anybody can access/download the video by just putting the link in the browser.

In this example the video isn't served from the (client side) `wwwroot` folder, but from a server side folder, see: `var videoPathFile`

***Client side `video` tag***

```
<video id="videostream" poster="@videoPoster" class="videostyle" oncontextmenu="return false;" controls disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="/VideoStream/@videoFileName" type="@ContentType;codecs=@Codecs" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.naar een nieuwere versie.
</video>
```

***/Server/Controllers/VideoStreamController.cs***

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;

namespace Mediatheek.Server.Controllers
{
    //[ApiController] 
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class VideoStreamController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment env;
        private readonly ILogger<VideoStreamController> logger;
        public VideoStreamController(ILogger<VideoStreamController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.env = env;
        }

        //[Authorize] // Doesn't work here, even when [ApiController] is uncommented
        [HttpGet("{file}")]
        public IActionResult StreamVideo(string file)
        {
            var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(env.ContentRootPath);
            var videoPathFile = Path.Combine(provider.Root, "Files", "Videos", $"{file}.mp4");
            var fileResponse = PhysicalFile(videoPathFile, "application/octet-stream");
            fileResponse.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
            fileResponse.FileDownloadName = "video.mp4"; // rename original filename, just for testing
            return fileResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand why some people think this question isn't useful or lacks research. Is it unclear? Without any comments I don't know what to do. Yesterday it made me question myself and it didn't feel good. But okay, it's a feature of this platform but I can't figure out why it exists in the first place, without having to leave a comment.

Comment: Jaap, I for one think your question looks fine.  I think your question is not related to Blazor but instead how to Authorize API call.  I suggest Google something like "how to authorize web api request in c#".  You will see a lot of examples that maybe can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Jason, thank you for your comment. I've googled for a solution. The problem here, I think, is that the `[Authorize]` attribute doesn't work on a controller which is directly accessed from the `<video>` tag. It's not an `HttpClient` request. I've looked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775942/how-do-i-serve-static-files-only-to-authorized-users, here: https://forums.asp.net/t/2172881.aspx?Protect+Static+Files+with+Authentication+on+ASP+NET+Core

Comment: And here: https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/how-can-i-protect-static-files-with-authorization-on-asp-net-core-4l0o#:~:text=We%20can%20protect%20static%20files,UseStaticFiles(...)%20. and here https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx

Comment: Why these examples don't work is (I think) because the combination of Blazor WASM, and the controller. `options.FallbackPolicy` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#static-file-authorization) for example doesn't work in Blazor WASM (afaik)

Comment: Minus Three on this question is actually to much for me to handle as a simple, but emotional, guy trying to do his best. When I submitted this question to SO I've worked for over an hour on the question alone English isn't my first language. Spend more than a day on googling stuff. When I first saw these negative responses (within a couple of minutes, how is that possible?) it made me angry. Now I'm just sad. I don't like being sad. I really don't.

Comment: Yup: `AuthorizationOptions.FallbackPolicy` isn't support in Blazor WASM, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#require-authorization-for-the-entire-app

Comment: It sounds like you did a good job getting to the root cause of the problem.  Unfortunately I don't have any experience with this FallbackPolicy requirement.  Were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: @JasonD Not yet, but I'm asking around When I've a solution I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `authorization` header isn't being sent with the request. As you stated yourself, it's not using a traditional `HttpClient` and loading via the browser, but problem is that it should be for `[Authroize]` to work as intended.

This means you'd need to convert the WASM code to read the `.mp4` as a byte stream and then send that over to the browser using `IJSRuntime` and build the video using JavaScript but that is very clunky and a terrible experience.

A better option is to use `HttpClient` to request the video URL, at least that way you know the client is authorized to know what the file path to the `mp4` is.

Comment: Yes, the problem lies in the use of the `<video>` tag in combination with JWT. I'm looking also into adding temporary request headers in combination with some sort of cookie authorization, but I still haven't got my code working the way it should, e.g. 'safe'.